# Change default file manager in Arch Linux with E17 to Dolphin

Tags: arch-linux, enlightenment

I am using Arch Linux with E17 as my DE.

However, I am not happy with the file manager that E17 comes with, so I researched a bit and decided to go with the Dolphin file manager (the one KDE comes with).

So I need the following info from the experts:

- What's the best place to get it from? Official packages? AUR? If yes, which, if no, where and how?
- And, of course, how to make it the default file manager so that it gets launched instead of E17's file manager.

Comment: No one? Should I look into the Arch Linux forums for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3):

To get it, try this:

```
sudo pacman -S kdebase-dolphin
```

(this is taken from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Graphical_9)

Comment: Hi Aditya, welcome to unix.SE.  I've edited your post slightly to improve the formatting and make it easier to read.  You can click the "edit" link yourself to see the source and understand how the formatting engine works.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you were asking for, but you can make E17 run ANY file manager just by right clicking on a folder/volume icon, selecting Open With... Other Application, and typing in the name of the file manager executable into the Run Anything prompt. I do this all the time with PCManFM. Probably not the best FM to be using with E17, but it sure is a heck of a lot better than E17's own FM.